# GNU Parallel combination of input parameters by index number

Tags: bash, unix, gnu-parallel

I know GNU Parallel is amazing at munching through all combinations of input parameters. I however have a script where I want the opposite, I have multiple arrays which I want to combine using a simple index.

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

letters='a b'
numbers='1 2'

f1(){
    echo $1 $2
    echo letter: $1
    echo number: $2
}
export -f f1

parallel f1 {1} {2} ::: $letters ::: $numbers
```

which gives:

```
a 1
letter: a
number: 1
a 2
letter: a
number: 2
b 1
letter: b
number: 1
b 2
letter: b
number: 2
```

I would just want to have this result though:

```
a 1
letter: a
number: 1
b 2
letter: b
number: 2
```

Any help appreciated, I didn't find an index switch in the (long) docs.

Comment: maybe you should use single string `'a1 b2'` - and inside `f1` split `'a1'` into `'a'` and `'1'` (and `'b2'` into `'b'` and `'2'`)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I didn't see that earlier. I am now using an approach like this:
paste <(echo "$letters") <(echo "$numbers") | parallel f1 {1} {2}

f1(){
 inputs=$1
 letter=`echo $inputs | cut --delimiter " " --fields 1`
 number=`echo $inputs | cut --delimiter " " --fields 2`
}

If you want to write your answer, i would accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want to *"link"* your arguments:

```
parallel --link echo {1} {2} ::: 1 2 3 ::: a b c
```

**Output**

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

---

As opposed to:

```
parallel echo {1} {2} ::: 1 2 3 ::: a b c
```

which produces all permutations:

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 a
2 b
2 c
3 a
3 b
3 c
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Turned out the version of parallel I was using didn't have this option yet :p

Comment: @tlhenvironment The old name for `--link` is `--xapply`. Newer version also support `:::+` which works like `--link` but which can be mixed with `:::` like: `parallel echo ::: a b c :::+ 1 2 3 ::: Green Blue`

Comment: That's great. I must say, I find the manual of parallel a bit convoluted :P

Comment: There's an excellent PDF here that might be helpful https://zenodo.org/record/1146014/files/GNU_Parallel_2018.pdf?download=1